# NoMethodError (undefined method `search=' for #<Profile:0x000000016d1fb8>) in production mode but not in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite, heroku

My web app works perfectly in development mode but in production mode i cant even log in. Once i log in there is an error which is:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `search=' for #<Profile:0x000000016d1fb8>).
```

The same error appears if i sign up and then create my profile. How do I solve this? I am working with ruby on rails in aws cloud 9 environment and am trying to deploy to heroku. I am using sqllite3 for development and postgressql for production.

this is my profilescontroller.rb

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :only_current_user
  # GET to /users/:user_id/profile/new
  def new
    # Render blank profile details form
    @profile = Profile.new
  end

  # POST to /users/:user_id/profile
  def create
    # Ensure that we have the user who is filling out form
    @user = User.find( params[:user_id] )
    # Create profile linked to this specific user
    @profile = @user.build_profile( profile_params )
    if @profile.save
      flash[:success] = "Profile Created"

      redirect_to user_path(id: params[:user_id] )
    else
      render action: :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find( params[:user_id] )
    @profile=@user.profile
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find( params[:user_id] )
    @profile = @user.profile
    if @profile.update_attributes(profile_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile Updated."
      #redirect to their profile page
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render action: :edit
    end
  end

  private
    def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :avatar, :age, :gender, :city, :collegeemail, :minimumage, :maximumage, :genderpreference, :collegepreference, :search)
    end

    def only_current_user
      @user = User.find( params[:user_id] )
      redirect_to(root_url) unless @user == current_user
    end

end
```

Comment: Do you have the same code for development and production? The issue you showed above suggests that there is no way to assign a value to `search` for `Profile`. 

Comment: Yes, I have run all migrations. Search was always in the profile model for me. I just redid the migration to ensure as well. Any idea what else could be wrong? I am using websolr addon as well. Could that be the source of my error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the table for the `Profile` model is not the same in production as in development. Specifically, it seems that the `search` column is missing, causing `Profile` not to have a getter and setter for `search`.

I assume you have forgotten to run a migration in production, which adds the `search` column to the table of the `Profile` model.

Comment: Yes, it was a migration problem. Thanks!

Comment: @saltedalmond why didn't you accept my answer then? Mine was first and more extensive in my opinion, hence the votes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Above error comes whenever we dont have the specific column present in the table. Make sure we have run the migration on the production or just have a look in to schema.rb file and look for column "search" in profile table.